# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to do a custom embed command and i got this error.

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'`

And this is my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(self, ctx,*, msg=None):

  if msg == None:
    await ctx.send("No Message has been provided.  Please write your message within 30secs.")
    def check(message):
      return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
      mes=await self.client.wait_for('message',check=check,timeout=30.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await ctx.send('Timeout! Please be quicker next time.')
    else:
      msg=mes.content
  em=discord.Embed(
    description=msg,
    timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
    color=discord.Color.random()).set_author(
    name=f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}',
    icon_url=f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
  await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

If u can patch it please say me below :(

Comment: Why are you passing in `self`? Is this code in a class? Perhaps ctx is not the argument you are expecting as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(self, ctx,*, msg=None):
```

If you're in a cog, you need to be doing `@commands.command`. When doing `client.command` decorator though, you're adding the callback itself (and it isn't called from the class). The *actual context* is passed to `self`, and `ctx` becomes your first argument (a string) while the other argument `msg` just stays as `None`.

If you are in a cog, then change it to a normal command.

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(self, ctx,*, msg=None):
```

Comment: Im not in a cog. So idk how to fix it.

Comment: Then you should be able to remove the `self` (keep the `@client.command`)

Answer (score 0):

```
@testy.command(name='d')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(ctx, msg=None):

  if msg == None:
    await ctx.send("No Message has been provided.  Please write your message within 30secs.")
    def check(message):
      return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
      mes=await testy.wait_for('message',check=check,timeout=30.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await ctx.send('Timeout! Please be quicker next time.')
    else:
      msg=mes.content

  em=discord.Embed(description=msg, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.random())
  em.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
  await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Using your code as a base, I tweaked a couple of things and verified it worked on my tester bot. You can see the name of my bot is "testy" so you'll want to replace that with your client.
The command is invoked with the command 'd' and then prompts the user for a text string. That string is then displayed in an embed with a timestamp and the user's discord name and avatar.
Hope this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me, i got this error "In embed.author.icon_url: Scheme "342c2c008fc053cd7b08dd18d2243687" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https')." and I deleted the embed.author.icon_url and worked! Thank you so much for the support!

Comment: Why was my answer accepted, then unaccepted?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are passing in for ctx, but it looks like you're passing in a string for ctx based off of the error, in which case there is no send() function for a string object